# ReturnUrl from mobile Login page not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, mobile, webforms

I have .net forms authentication rolemanager type webwsite with a login page, login.aspx.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Login" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="7200" path="/"/>
</authentication>

login.aspx redirect:
Response.Redirect("mobileLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"))
```

If a user accesses my page through a mobile device, I redirect them to mobileLogin.aspx., but when they login from mobile device from mobileLogin.aspx, it doesn't take user to the ReturnUrl it is saying...

For example this works, by redirecting to /admin/ folder

```
http://mysite.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2f
```

This does NOT work, it redirects to home page even after logging in,

```
http://mysite.com/mobilelogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2f
```

How can I get the redirect from mobile?

Comment: Does the code-behind for mobilelogin.aspx handle the `ReturnUrl` QueryString variable?

Comment: No the mobilelogin does not, but the login.aspx does this on the redirect: Response.Redirect("mobileLogin.aspx" + Request.RawUrl.Split("x")(1)). I will update the question

Comment: That's the problem.  You have to add code in mobilelogin.aspx.cs that handles the QueryString variable similar to the way login does.  And use `Request.QueryString` to access QueryString variables, not the `Request.RawUrl.Split`.

Comment: ok, i can probably figure out the request.querystring but not the handling of it on redirect. i thought it was just automatic

Comment: The URL is HTML encoded.  ASP.NET includes methods for encoding and decoding HTML.  Once you've decoded it, you can just call `Response.Redirect`, passing the decoded URL.

Comment: I just don't understand why the login control will ReturnUrl for login.aspx, but not with mobileLogin.aspx. They both use the same login control.